# ajax.actionlink replace vs replacewith

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm using `Ajax.ActionLink` in a view that I have on an ASP.NET-MVC application and I'm using `InsertionMode.Replace`, but I see there's also a `ReplaceWith` option. What's the difference between the two? Does one replace something more/less than the other one. I need the div I'm replacing to be completely replaced with the partial view.

I can't find a comparison anywhere on google

Comment: What? Where did you find that option? There's no reference of it in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.insertionmode(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: I was typing into VisualStudio and it came up with 4 options, one was replacewith

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using? Do you use external libraries?

Comment: I'm using MVC-5 with Entity Framework

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`Replace` will replace the content with the new content. `ReplaceWith` will replace the entire element.

```
<body>
    <div id="myResults">
        <p> Results will be displayed here </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Response from ajax

```
<span>This is the result</span>
```

with `Replace` option targeting `myResults`

```
<body>
    <div id="myResults">
        <span>This is the result</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

using `ReplaceWith` option targeting `myResults`

```
<body>
    <span>This is the result</span>
</body>
```

Comment: It would have been better if Replace were titled as ReplaceContents

Comment: @SimpleFellow on top of that, you can achieve either of these goals by just manipulating the UpdateTargetId, right?